# how can i solve console. error: This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console

I always clicked on this section and was able to perform manual checks from chrome.I did not do any changes to this component file as I am only involved in testing I only touch test code.
All of sudden when I click on Documents section after login to app and navigate click on document menu item >I see blank screen
It would be great if you can help me figure out what is crashing app when i click on DocumentOverview section with console error : -

**bundle-1538746678204.js:158394 Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.in DocumentsOverview (created by inject-DocumentsOverview-with-documentStore-settingsStore)****

Comment: It seems you are rendering an undefined variable in your JSX. Post some code to get more coincise help.

Comment: You are either rendering an undefined component, or an undefined prop of a component. It's impossible for us to help if you don't post the code where this error is happening to you. Please post your code, and post your package.json. If you can, post your code in a sandbox, this ways it's easier for the community to help you.

Comment: The app's code, not React's code.

Comment: @Dave : by app code for this component - do you mean code from scm for this component?thats too big to share in question

Comment: @vm31 Then nobody will be able to help, simple as that. The `render` method isn't returning anything React knows how to render. Good luck!

Comment: @Dave above is the js file that is causing error click on Document overview

Comment: You're formatting it wrong; use a code block, not a quote.

Comment: i think it was our internal application development bug. issue solved when they fixed and master got updated. not an issue anymore